# How do I fit a wide table to a page?

Tags: tables

Using the code below I get the attached output. I want to make a table consisting of nine columns but currently it is too wide to be displayed completely.

```
 \begin{table}[ht]
    \caption{Survey Findings Table \& metrics}
    \centering 
    \scriptsize{
    \begin{tabular}{l*{9}{c}r }
    \hline\hline 
\end{tabular}}
\end{table}
```

[image: This is the resulting output.]

Comment: Set the table in a smaller font??  For example, `{\tiny\begin{tabular}...\end{tabular}}`

Comment: Perhaps you could abbreviate the headers or rotate the header text by 90 degrees.

Comment: To fit things also the [adjustbox package](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/adjustbox) is often useful.

Comment: `\scriptsize` doesn't take an argument, by the way. It is a switch.

Answer (score 2):

For fitting a table to page width you can do one or combined items from the following list:

- Add `@{}` before and after column specifications to remove space between the columns, e.g. `{@{}*{9}{l}@{}}`.
- Reduce the font size, but don't exaggerate with this. The table can
  become difficult to read and ugly.
- If circumstance allowe, consider to rotate the table for 90 degrees by using `sidewaytable` from the [`rotating` package](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/rotating).
- In case, when contents of cells are shorter then their headers, see if it is appropriate to turn headers for 90 degrees. For this you can use `\rotatebox{90}{...}` or `\rothead` from [`makecell` package](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/makecell), or see if breaking the column headers into two lines with hyphenations looks fine.

To say anything more particularly to your problem, you should provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) which demonstrate your problem.